# How do I hide a field from display in the Experience Editor's component editor?

Tags: experience-editor, content-editor, pipelines

I need to hide a template field on both Content Editor and Experience Editor. For Content Editor, I could achieve it by overriding the GetFields pipeline. It still shows up on the Experience Editor. How do I hide it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? if you just want to hide it in experience editor only, you can simply check for `PageMode.IsExperienceEditor` in your view.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better option to use security settings on the field to hide it?

Comment: I need to hide it from the component's edit modal. Security route would be ideal, but we have not used field level security yet, so was wondering if we have an alternate way :-)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out we were using a SuperFieldEditor for our X-Editor to provide access to the template fields for the component.

[Super Field Editor](https://jeffdarchuk.com/2015/12/20/super-field-editor/)

So I fixed the issue by disabling Field access to all authors. Now it was little tricky since I wanted to write to the field, but not allow read. Here's what I ended up setting. Works!

[image]